# Keras Model Always Predicts the Same Result

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've written the following Keras model:

```py
import configuration_reader

# Import libraries
import pandas
import keras
from pprint import pprint

# Import TensorFlow
import tensorflow as tf

# Import keras dependencies
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import GRU

# Read configuration
configuration = configuration_reader.read_configuration()
training_configuration = configuration['train']
MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH = training_configuration['max_document_length']
MAX_SIZE = training_configuration['max_size']
LOSS_FUNCTION = training_configuration['loss']
TENSORBOARD_DIR = configuration['tensorboard']['dir']
ACTIVATION_FUNCTION = training_configuration['activation_function']
EMBEDDING_SIZE = training_configuration['embedding_size']
LSTM_UNITS = training_configuration['lstm_units']
RECURRENT_DROPOUT = training_configuration['recurrent_dropout']
DROPOUT = training_configuration['dropout']
MAX_LABEL = §training_configuration['max_label']
BATCH_SIZE = training_configuration['batchSize']
EPOCHS = training_configuration['epochs']
WORDS_FEATURE = training_configuration['wordsFeature']
MODEL_FILE_NAME = configuration['modelFileName']
LEARNING_RATE = training_configuration['learning_rate']


def get_data():
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

    dbpedia = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset('dbpedia')
    x_train = pandas.Series(dbpedia.train.data[:, 1])
    y_train = pandas.Series(dbpedia.train.target)
    x_test = pandas.Series(dbpedia.test.data[:, 1])
    y_test = pandas.Series(dbpedia.test.target)

    tokenizer = Tokenizer()
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x_train)

    x_train_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_train)
    x_test_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_test)

    tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH)
    X_train = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(x_train_sequences, mode='binary')
    X_test = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(x_test_sequences, mode='binary')

    num_classes = len(y_test)
    num_classes_unique = len(y_test.unique())
    print(u'Number of classes: {}'.format(num_classes_unique))

    y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
    y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
    print('y_train shape:', y_train.shape)
    print('y_test shape:', y_test.shape)
    return (X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, num_classes, tokenizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    (X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, num_classes, tokenizer) = get_data()

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(MAX_SIZE, EMBEDDING_SIZE))
    model.add(GRU(LSTM_UNITS, recurrent_dropout=RECURRENT_DROPOUT))
    model.add(Dropout(DROPOUT))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes))
    model.add(Activation(ACTIVATION_FUNCTION))

    model.compile(loss=LOSS_FUNCTION,
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(LEARNING_RATE),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    print(model.summary())

    tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=TENSORBOARD_DIR,
                                                       histogram_freq=1,
                                                       write_graph=True)

    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                        epochs=EPOCHS,
                        shuffle=True,
                        validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                        callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

    score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test,
                           batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=1)

    model.save(MODEL_FILE_NAME)

    print(u'Loss: {}'.format(score[0]))
    print(u'Accuracy: {}'.format(score[1]))

    def _predict(text):
        text_to_predict = pandas.Series([text])
        tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text_to_predict)
        text_to_predict_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text_to_predict)
        to_predict = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(text_to_predict_sequences, mode='binary')
        prediction = model.predict(to_predict, steps=1000)
        predicted_class_index = prediction.argmax(axis=1)
        pprint(predicted_class_index)

    while True:
        text_input = input('Enter: ')
        _predict(text_input)
```

This is the configuration I'm using:

```py
{   
    {
        "logDir": "graph",
        "port": 9001,
        "modelFileName": "model.h5",
        "tensorboard": {
            "dir": "./graph"
        }
    },
    "train": {
        "wordsFeature": "words",
        "epochs": 3,
        "batchSize": 32,
        "dropout": 0.5,
        "recurrent_dropout": 0.5,
        "max_label": 15,
        "lstm_units": 128,
        "embedding_size": 200,
        "activation_function": "sigmoid",
        "loss": "binary_crossentropy",
        "max_size": 1000,
        "max_document_length": 50,
        "learning_rate": 0.001
    }
}
```

The model trains as expected and gets an accuracy of about 98% when evaluating. 
But there are two things, that are quite unusual there.

1. The predictions of the model are inaccurate
2. After I predict the first label, all of the next predictions are exactly the same.

As for the first point, there might be something wrong with my model. But for the second, I'm really confused as to why this is happening?
Does anybody have an idea, why this is happening and what the solution might be?

I'm using Keras with the TensorFlow backend (CUDA version).

Comment: is your dataset inbalanced?

Comment: @WilmarvanOmmeren It shouldn't, as I'm using the dbpedia dataset, which is already splitted into train and testing data and should be evenly distributed.

Comment: Just check it, because your model is probably overfitting. Also 3 epochs is very little, increasing might improve the accuracy. Finally, you are using `binary_crossentropy` as loss. This means that your last dense layer should have 1 node (`num_classes = `).

Comment: @WilmarvanOmmeren Yeah I've seen that it is loading the DBPedia dataset with "small" (only 560 samples, altough evenly distributed). I've now changed it to "big" to get all the training data. But I'm getting a memory error while calling "load_dataset". Not sure why that happens, but I'll try it again later today on another system.
So, you mean, I should change the units of the Dense layer to 1?

Comment: @WilmarvanOmmeren I've trained it on the bigger dataset and the predictions seem to be more accurate now. But I'm still facing my 2nd problem. _After I predict the first label, all of the next predictions are exactly the same._ Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @ThomasGassmann I have the same issue as you. Have you found a solution for this?